# How to make notification component react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have component for notification in notif.js

```
import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component'
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component';

export const notify = (props) => {
  store.addNotification({
    title: props.title,
    message: props.message,
    type: props.type,
    insert: "top",
    container: "top-right",
    animationIn: [ "animate__fadeIn"],
    animationOut: [ "animate__fadeOut"],
    dismiss: {
      duration: 5000,
    }
  })
}
```

I want to use this in my other component but I don't know how to make it happen, this is one of the components

```
import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component'
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component';
import { notify } from 'notif'

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ReactNotification />
            <button onClick= {openNotify1}>get Notify Success</button>
            <button onClick= {openNotify2}>get Notify Danger</button>
            <button onClick= {openNotify3}>get Notify Warning</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

export default App;

Comment: Why are you creating your own when there are builtin components are available... checkout npm package "toastify"

Comment: What is `openNotify1`? Can you show much more of your usage please? I can't even tell if you call notify, so all I can say is make sure you call `notify`.